# Learning how to read and design a data driven xml document

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have been working on using VS 2022 with C#.net to read data from a XML document I had wrote up. The problems I am having is mainly understanding how the xml document really should be laid out / coded, and how best to search this document to provide the necessary data to the controls I need them to go to. So mainly my question is, is there a better way to layout my xml document? Also when trying to read the data what would be the best method? I have tried a few different solutions. Xmlserializer, XMLReader or dealing with the document data itself or even creating a class to hold the data so I can parse it. So far I get some empty lines and also get the data and I am just not very happy with those results. The code does run however I just need it to be more specific per item than what it is.

My code for parsing the current format looks like this and I was adding it into a treeview to get an idea for how it was actually reading the data.

```
`
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Wagon_Wheel_Solution
{
    public partial class All_Items : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public All_Items()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.TopLevel = false;

            List<Custom_all_btn> btnlist = new List<Custom_all_btn>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                btnlist.Add(new Custom_all_btn(i.ToString() + " control") { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 80 });
            }

            btnlist.Reverse();
            foreach (Custom_all_btn btn in btnlist)
            {
                pnlItems.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
            // Load the XML document
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Bizstorecard\MC500_Startup.xml"); // Replace with your XML file path

            // Display XML nodes in the TreeView
            DisplayXmlNodes(xmlDoc.DocumentElement, treeViewXML.Nodes);
            /*foreach (Custom_all_btn btn in this.Controls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(btn.Name.ToString());
            }*/
            groupSandwiches.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            groupSpeciality.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            groupHotSoup.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            groupSomething.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pnlItems.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            //pnlTotals.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            xmlDoc = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void PopulateItems(XmlNode xmlNode, Custom_all_btn btn)
        {


        }

        private void DisplayXmlNodes(XmlNode xmlNode, TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = treeNodes.Add(xmlNode.Name);

            String value = xmlNode.InnerText;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlNode.InnerText) && value != "InnerText:")
            {
                newNode.Nodes.Add(xmlNode.Value);
            }
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
            {




                DisplayXmlNodes(childNode, newNode.Nodes);


            }

            if (xmlNode.Attributes != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in xmlNode.Attributes)
                {
                    if (attribute.Value != null)
                    {
                        newNode.Nodes.Add($"{attribute.Name}: {attribute.InnerText}");
                    }
                }
            }



        }

        private void All_Items_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
`
```

I will attach my xml data file as well (hmmm it doesn't seem to allow me to attach a file just yet). Also thank you in advance for anyone that can help point me in the right direction.

I would like to have each item separated almost like records would be my goal.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure out how to post a file so I did a screen capture of some of the xml document

Comment: That's because there's no option to post files. The text body of the post needs to be complete so that it doesn't rely on external resources to be complete and remains complete over time.  See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: That said, this looks like far too much information to be a [mre] about XML serialization. Try to cut it down.  Plus, you're asking opinion-based questions about what you "should" do or what's "best", which makes your question off-topic to begin with.

Comment: Best way of adding file data is to use the icon <> and then paste the file into one of the views.  Designing an XML file is like designing a database.  Most XML files are machine generated and have many levels of descendants which is not needed.  An XML file can only have one root tag.  So next level you can think of the tags are tables in a database.  Then next level are the rows of the database and the last level is the column data.  You can create a c# dataset and then add tables.  Then use the dataset method DS.WriteXml() to create an XML file.

Comment: Ok I apologize if what I asked was confusing or misleading in any way and thank you for your comments and help.

Comment: I'm afraid the question, while interesting, is out of scope for StackOverflow. Try the xml.com Slack channel, which is much more receptive to open-ended discussion, though you never know what tangents it will go off on.

Comment: Thank you Michael I will keep that in mind and probably will use that

Comment: Just paste the text of the XML directly into the question formatted as code (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following.  You can use the Dataset ReadXml to import the data to a dataset. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Configuration");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Global");
            dt.Columns.Add("Startup_Screen", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sandwich_Image_Path", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Meat_Image_Path", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "All_Items", @"c:\bizstorecard\Images\Sandwiches", @"c:\bizstorecard\Images\Meats" });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            dt = new DataTable("Sandwiches");
            dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Whole_Price", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Half_Price", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Regular", 11.99, 6.99 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Hot Sandwich", 12.99, 7.99 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Combo Meat Sandwich", 12.99, 7.99 });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration>
  <Global>
    <Startup_Screen>All_Items</Startup_Screen>
    <Sandwich_Image_Path>c:\bizstorecard\Images\Sandwiches</Sandwich_Image_Path>
    <Meat_Image_Path>c:\bizstorecard\Images\Meats</Meat_Image_Path>
  </Global>
  <Sandwiches>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Name>Regular</Name>
    <Whole_Price>11.99</Whole_Price>
    <Half_Price>6.99</Half_Price>
  </Sandwiches>
  <Sandwiches>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Name>Hot Sandwich</Name>
    <Whole_Price>12.99</Whole_Price>
    <Half_Price>7.99</Half_Price>
  </Sandwiches>
  <Sandwiches>
    <Number>3</Number>
    <Name>Combo Meat Sandwich</Name>
    <Whole_Price>12.99</Whole_Price>
    <Half_Price>7.99</Half_Price>
  </Sandwiches>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That actually helped me a lot and I greatly appreciate it!